# Monitor CPU cumulative usage by process over time

Tags: cpu, cpu-load

I'd like to collect CPU usage info over some time to answer the question which process stresses my system *overall* the most. Is it Firefox? Is it ffmpeg? Etc.
I have htop installed, but there one cannot configure the sampling interval as I see it. I also looked at nmon, glances and other tools, but none of them seem to have a "recording" facility where one can collect a sample over a longer time and *aggregate* it to get average CPU usage *in percentage*.

In the end I'd like to have an answer like this (I can do some aggregation in a spreadsheet tool or with R code on my own, that's no problem):

All Firefox processes / threads used 20% of the CPU in the last hour, all Chrome processes used 10%, etc. - independent of the number of CPU cores I have.

The reason for this is that my system, while having a lot of RAM and an 8-core CPU, seems to become quite slow and sluggish over time.. and then I'd like to identify the culprit. Just looking at htop from time to time does not help in my experience.

Comment: You could use something like Prometheus. You would need Prometheus itself and the Node Exporter (in this case your PC=a node) which would monitor and record stats from your PC. `sudo apt-get install prometheus prometheus-node-exporter` It will take you a bit of reading/setup: https://prometheus.io/ Once running, node exporter will constantly collect stats in the background and you can then use the (web-based) Prometheus query tools to query any stats.